# How to write a general state in Fock space in the form of a series of products of $b_k^\dagger$s on a vacuum state?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform

Consider the state in bosonic system with $N$ sites with periodic boundary condition
$$|n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_{N/2}>=\left(\prod_{i\in\{0,\pm 1,\dots,\pm N/2\}}\frac{(b^\dagger_i)^{n_i}}{\sqrt{n_i!}}\right)|0>$$

I want to transform this state to $k$-space, I've tried to express it as

\begin{align}
|n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_{N/2}>&=\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i\in\{0,\pm 1,\dots,\pm N/2\}}\left(\prod_{i\in\{0,\pm 1,\dots,\pm N/2\}}\frac{(b^\dagger_i)^{n_i}}{\sqrt{n_i!}}\right)|0>\\
&=\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i\in\{0,\pm 1,\dots,\pm N/2\}}\prod_{i\in\{0,\pm 1,\dots,\pm N/2\}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n_i!}}\sum_{k_i}e^{-\text{i}(k_{1_1}+k_{1_2}+\cdots+k_{1_{n_1}}-k_{-1_1}+\cdots+2(k_2+\cdots+k_{-2}+\cdots)+\cdots+m(k_m+\cdots+k_{-m}+\cdots)+\cdots))} \delta{(\cdots))}b^\dagger_{k_{1_1}}b^\dagger_{k_{1_2}}\cdots b^\dagger_{k_{1_{n_1}}}b^\dagger_{k_{-1}}\cdots b^\dagger_{k_{N/2}}\cdots\\
\end{align}

Which is extremely complex, even for the case $n_1=n_2=\cdots=n_{N/2}=1$. It seems to be not practical to work on this state.

The question I meet is, I have a Hamiltonian in $k$-space, which have the following form
$$\mathcal{H}=\epsilon_kb^\dagger_kb_k+\delta_{k_1+k_2-k_3-k_4}\epsilon_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}b^\dagger_{k_1}b^\dagger_{k_2}b_{k_3}b_{k_4}+\delta_{k_1+k_2+k_3-k_4-k_5-k_6}\epsilon b^\dagger_{k_1}b^\dagger_{k_2}b^\dagger_{k_3}b_{k_4}b_{k_5}b_{k_6}+\cdots$$
where Einstein's summation rule has been applied. The Hamiltonian contains finite terms.

For example, I want to know the energy of the state $b_k|n,n,n\cdots>$ because I want to calculate some ensemble average, which is usually easier when woking in $k$-space, but transforming this state to $k$-space stumped me. Is there any document or book about **how to write a general state in Fock space in the form of a series of products of $b_k^\dagger$s on a vacuum state?** If not, any related reference would also be greatly helpful.